# com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied running a react-native initial project

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

I am studying react-native.And I follow the tutorials on the website.When I execute "react-native run-ios". It happens some error messages.

```
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/Mapple/Developer/React-native-workspace/HelloWorld 

[19:16:32] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[19:16:32] <START> Crawling File System
[Hot Module Replacement] Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.

2016-07-30T19:16:32,265: [cli] Failed to open /Users/Mapple/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

2016-07-30T19:16:32,265: [cli] Failed to open /Users/Mapple/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

Watchman:  watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null 2016-07-30T19:16:32,265: [cli] Failed to open /Users/Mapple/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

 ERROR  watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null 2016-07-30T19:16:32,265: [cli] Failed to open /Users/Mapple/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

Error: watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null 2016-07-30T19:16:32,265: [cli] Failed to open /Users/Mapple/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/Mapple/Developer/React-native-workspace/HelloWorld/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:198:18)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)
```

I find there is no file-com.github.facebook.watchman.plist in the /Users/Mapple/Library/LaunchAgents. I tried a variety of ways, but it does not play a role。
I will crazy。

Packages Version:

1.node: v6.1.0
2.watchman: 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem.There is a file in my directory called “org.lantern.plist”.I guess it's because of the Lantern software.So when I delete /Users/Mapple/Library/LaunchAgents and re create it,and re execute the command "react-native init HelloWorld",my problem has solved.